# Displaying two column data grid

Tags: design-patterns, design, responsive-design, best-practice, lean-ux

In my recent application I have to design and implement a data grid which will be having only two columns. This actually use as matrix for reference purposes.

User behavior is like
Railcar operators want to measure remaining capacity of oil in each tank by galloons. As you know due to the shape of the tank (cylinder) capacity varies with the height. What they normally do is they insert the measuring tape (stick) in to the tank and measure the height of the oil level. Then there is matrix (reference chart) to get the capacity for the relevant height. Only two columns (height in inches and capacity in gallons) contains in the grid. So my task is to design that chart in a very usable manner.

This is one of the approach came to my mind is

[image]

As I said the operate wants to quickly find the capacity when he got the measured height. Table will be expanded to 180 inches and it is quite lengthy. So operator has to scroll the table and scan data to locate the relevant capacity.

My suggestion here is adding few clickable indicators (place holders that represent ranges in inches) will be help full for the users to locate the data easily. For example if operator measured height as 6.7 inches , he can easily click on "6" (from the right panel) then the table will be scrolled to show the data starting from 6. then he can easily locate the 6.7 and capacity. Number range for right panel can be calculated based on the available data set. Either we can set the range as 10, 20, 30 so on. (it will be based on data set). Numbers on right panel will not be scrollable and relevant to the screen height. Only the data set will be scrollable.

Primary requirement here is to quick way to locate the volume of the tank. Share your thoughts on this ?

Thanks
Nuwan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if there could be a solution where the user doesn't have to hunt and scroll to find the data they are looking for. Since, if I'm understanding correctly, they are measuring and getting an explicit value, they could enter this value in a field and be given the exact information they need.

[image: Two Examples: Text field & Slider]